# jQuery returns undefined with POST call

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm sure this is something really easy, but I'm such a noob when I get stuck on these things... It's been over 2 hours, I hate when this happens :(

Why is this returning undefined?

```
function userExists(user) {
$.post("misc/user_exists.php",  {user: user},
        function(result) {
            return '' + result + '';
        });
});
```

The php file is returning the user name perfectly fine as I'm seeing it in the responses from firebug. But then this function is useless, when I do an alert after calling it, it's always undefined, whether I return a string, a boolean, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Is `result` undefined?  Or is the return value of `userExists(user)` undefined?

Comment: Try: console.log( result ); What does Firebug say?

Comment: the result of userExists(user). result is the user name when it exists.

Comment: result is fine inside the function, but outside is not working, I mean when I call userExists(user) it gives me undefined. But if I put an alert inside the function result is alerted correctly (name of the user)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$.post` request is asynchronous, so when you run `return '' + result + '';` it's not actually returning data to anywhere. Instead, trigger a different event from inside the AJAX success function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the correct dataType parameter for the jQuery post command.
Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the return will only affect the ajax.sucess callback from the post method. Try this:

```
function userExists(user, callback) //because this can be async, you need a callback...
{
    $.post("misc/user_exists.php",  {user: user},
    function(result) 
    {
        if(callback)
            callback(result)
        return '' + result + '';
    });
};
userExists('someUser', function(result)
{
     alert('' + result + '')
});
```

or, you can make sure that the call is not async:

```
function userExists(user) //because this can be async, you need a callback...
{
    var res;
    $.post("misc/user_exists.php",  {user: user},
    function(result) 
    {
        res = result;
    });
    return res;
};
$.ajax({async:false}); 
alert('' + userExists('someUser'+ '');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this

```
function userExists(user) {
    var username = '';
$.post("misc/user_exists.php",  {user: user},
        function(result) {

            username = result ;
        });
   return username;
});
```

Comment: instead of undefined, yours is going to return ''. The call is asynchronous.